# Unset Environment Variable in grunt-env

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, environment-variables, unset

Is there a way to unset environment variables with `grunt-env`? I know I can set them from the module, and there is even a way to set them to a value only if it doesn't exist. However, [the project's GitHub page](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env) does not seem to show how to unset them. Any solution would be better if it also included a way to unset *only if the variable is already set*. Suggestions for other modules are welcome, as well.

Is there perhaps a value I could set the variable to, like `undefined` or `null` or `empty string`? Forgive me, I'm not too well-versed in environment variables.

The reason I am asking this is because I am creating an `express` app, and I may want to set some values, which would be controlled by environment variables, back to the defaults, and this would require either setting the variable to a specific value or unsetting it. I would rather go with unsetting it, if possible, so I don't have to remember which value to set it to.

Answer (score -1):

This plugin is setting env variables only within the grunt process - those variables will **not be visible for other processes at all**! So you will not be able to set shell environment variables for your express app with this grunt plugin.

I also advice you not to set shell env variables with your build tools, but have them defined in bash file and loaded when the server is booted.

Comment: What I meant was, is there a way to unset the variables for the grunt tasks themselves, not other shell processes?

Comment: I have an Express app created (or started) with a Grunt task. This is what I am trying to set/unset environment variables for, so yes, they will be visible to my Express app, and yes, I can set them for said Express app. Is there a way to unset environment variables **for another Grunt task**?